# Создание Button программно

Tags: xcode, swift

Пытаюсь созданиях кнопку Button программно. Вот код:

```
 let btn = UIButton(type: .custom) as UIButton
        btn.backgroundColor = .blue
        btn.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Action), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
```

Ошибка в этом месте:

```
#selector(Action)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedButton), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func tappedButton() { 
// описание метода
}
```

Comment: Пишет следующую ошибку в селекторе «use of unresolved identifier ‘tuppedButton’

Comment: Будьте внимательней. Вы опечатались не tuppedButton а tappedButton. Название селектора должно совпадать с названием метода.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте кнопку в коде, в функции viewDidload и установите ее местоположение на экране:

[image: Создание кнопки в коде]